# Unable to Update Laravel API One to Many Relationship data on Angular Frontend

Tags: php, angular, laravel

I have Angular App connected with Laravel API. In Laravel API there are one to many relationship between Employee and Salary Models.
Employee.php

```
protected $fillable = ['birth_date','first_name','last_name','gender','hire_date'];

    protected $primaryKey = 'emp_no';

     public function salaries(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Salary::class, 'emp_no','emp_no');
    }
```

Salary.php

```
protected $fillable = ['salary','from_date','to_date'];

    public function employee(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'emp_no');
    }
```

EmployeeUpdate Controller is

```
public function updateEmployee(Request $request, $id)
{
    $employee = Employee::find($id);

    if (is_null($employee)) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Employee not found'], 404);
    }
 $employee->update($request->validate([
        'emp_no' => 'required',
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'gender' => 'required',
        'hire_date' => 'required'
]));
$employee->salaries()->update($request->validate([
'emp_no' => 'required',
        'salary' => 'required',
        'from_date' => 'required',
        'to_date' => 'required'

    ]));
    return response($employee, 200);
}
```

api route for update

```
Route::put('updateEmployee/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController@updateEmployee');
```

my data.service.ts is like this

```
 updateData(id: string, data: any) {
    return this.httpClient.put('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/updateEmployee/'+id, data);
  }
```

and employee-edit.component.ts

```
updateEmployee() {
    this.dataService.updateData(this.id, this.employee).subscribe(res => {
      this.data = res;
      this.employee = this.data;
      console.log(res);
    })
  }
```

my Salary Update Angular form

```
<h4>Salary Details</h4>
 
 <div class="salary-details" *ngFor="let salary of employee.salaries">
   <div class="table">
      <div class="form-group row">
         <label for="salary" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Salary</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="text" name="salary" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="salary.salary">
         </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group row">
         <label for="from_date" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">From Date</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="date" name="from_date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="salary.from_date">
         </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group row">
         <label for="to_date" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">To Date</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="date" name="to_date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="salary.to_date">
         </div>
      </div>
      <br>
   </div>
 </div>
```

but when I try to update Employee Model data is updating well but not updating Salary Model data inspect encounting folllowing error
`ERROR  Object { headers: {…}, status: 422, statusText: "Unprocessable Content", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/updateEmployee/1", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/updateEmployee/1: 422 Unprocessable Content", error: {…} }`

how could I fix this problem?